# password_hash: any advantages of automatically generated salt over manual?

Tags: php, password-encryption

If I understand correct, any PHP upgrade, or moving to different server will make previously hashed passwords (stored in database) useless? Because the salt will be different on a new system.

This makes me curious about the use cases for automatically generated salt.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431031/passwords-hashed-differently-on-different-servers

Comment: Of course there is an advantage - they're quite random and you never have to worry about the salt. And I have never heard of an upgrade or move destroying `password_verify()` ability to resolve the hash. Once the hash is created it can always be resolved AFAIK.

Comment: *It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one.* ([function-password-hash.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)).

Comment: The generated (or manual) salt is stored as part of the hash returned from `password_hash`. You shouldn't be using anything other than `password_verify` (and `password_needs_rehash`) from that point on, and all they require is the original composite hash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) now (as of PHP 7.1.*) only uses `bcrypt` for hashing passwords. Salt is saved along with the hash, so upgrade or moving to another server will not make hashes useless.

As **@Jay Blanchard** says [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999595/password-hash-any-advantages-of-automatically-generated-salt-over-manual/39999748#comment67276968_39999595), auto salts are an advantage because you just don't have to care. All is conveniently and automatically handled.

You even *should not* create the salt yourself, as it is also very [easy to make a mistake](https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/seven-ways-to-screw-up-bcrypt.html) when generating the salt yourself (non-random salt, incorrect random source for salt, etc).

Furthermore, the `salt` option is deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0 in `password_hash` `bcrypt` algorithm, so PHP will always use automatically generated salt.

Answer (score 4):

The salt is generated for each password and is stored as a part of the string you get back from the password_hash function. So it will be different for each time you hash a password. The reason we use salt in passwords is to get a new hash every time one is created, so if two users use the password "hunter2" they will be stored as totally different values in the database making rainbow tables useless.

So moving to a new server will not make the previously hashed passwords useless.

Comment: [Even when 2 Batman's use the same passphrase](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) ;)

Answer (score -2):

if you want to use manual salt, you can use it. even if you move to new server, the previous password will not be useless.

Trick is you can store your manual salt string where you usually store constants of your site, For example, Db username, DB password....

so even if you move to the new server you still use your manual salt string and previously salted data.

Comment: A site-wide static salt for all users, also known as "pepper", is no substitute for a per-user salt. It can be used as an additional security measure, but never a replacement.