# I cannot login using password_hash

Tags: php, mysql

So, for my class project, I have developed a web app that works totally fine no matter where I move it. However, I am running into an issue with the PHP function

```php
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

My issue is when I do a dump of the database to import into the runtime environment for my class it is not allowing me to log in with the password from the old system. However, if I do a password reset I can get in but I noticed that the values are changing.

Is there a way to move the data from one system to the other, keeping the preexisting values without having to reset them?

Login form

```
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST["username"]);  
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST["password"]); 

    $query = "SELECT UserId,FirstName,LastName,Password FROM yztp_gt_users.user_login where yztp_gt_users.user_login.email = '$username';";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);  
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
    {  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {
            $hash = $row["Password"];
            $uid = $row["UserId"];
            $firstname = $row["FirstName"];
            $lastname = $row["LastName"];

             if(password_verify($password, $hash))
             {  
                $_SESSION["uid"] = $uid;
                $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $firstname;
                $_SESSION["LastName"] = $lastname;
             }  
             else  
             {  
                  $error_message = '<label>Wrong user name or password</label>';  
             }  
        }  
    }
```

Registration form

```
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST["password"]); 
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST["email"]);
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST["firstname"]);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST["lastname"]);

    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);  

    $login = "INSERT INTO social_users.user_login(UUID,Password,Email) values(uuid(),'$password','$email');";

    if(mysqli_query($dbconn, $login))  
    {
        $query = "SELECT uuid FROM yztp_gt_users.user_login WHERE email = '$email'";  
        $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);  
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {                       
                if(mysqli_query($dbconn, $profile))
                {
                    echo '<script>alert("Please Check your email for activation")</script>';
                    $_SESSION["username"] = $email;
                    $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $firstname;
                    $_SESSION["LastName"] = $lastname;
                    $_SESSION["id"] = $row["uuid"];
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script>alert("Error Adding Profile Information")</script>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I found my answer but I am using PHP 7.3.17  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999595/password-hash-any-advantages-of-automatically-generated-salt-over-manual/39999748) and our classroom runtime is PHP 7.3.17

Comment: I am moving both the application and database and they are a AIO. Our dev environments are on centos 7 and our runtime is RHLE 8. both are using the latest PHP and MYSQL.

Comment: are you asking for the login code?

Comment: Do you use `password_verify()` to verify the password, or do you try to hash the password again?

Comment: @frieder yes, I am using the password_verify(). I have included my login code

Comment: `$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST["password"]);`  there's your problem. Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on this value (or ever really). It's not even being used in your query for starters. Second, let me introduce you to the wonderful world of prepared statements ~ https://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Phil - LOL! that is hilarious "let me introduce you to the wonderful world of prepared statements." We were instructed to use mysqli_real_escape_string to prevent injection. or did I not interpret that correctly?

Comment: You were instructed poorly. I'm sorry

Comment: @Phil - well I guess you cant expect much from the public schooling system here in San Jose, CA

Comment: If you _must_ use string escaping, don't use it on the posted password value when verifying. All that aside, for a simple value like `Password123`, it shouldn't make a difference. More debugging is required... how are you storing the password hash? Are you doing anything to the posted value before running `password_hash()`? Are you checking for leading / trailing whitespace on values (hint, use [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php))

Comment: @Phil - You are AWESOME! So, I looked at the two differences on when running the mysq_real_escape_strings on my dev systems and the runtime. they remove and replace differently. So the values are different between the two.

Comment: I am posting the registration PHP

Comment: In the absence of prepared statements, only use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on values that are directly used within queries. This means that you should not use it on either of your `$_POST['password']` strings. In your registration code, you would use it on the `$password` hash before it goes in your query. But seriously, use prepared statements and maybe get extra credit ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Phil - thank you! I will run with your suggestion.

Comment: You can add the correct answer and accept it. This will help people who have a similar problem.

Comment: @frieder - The use of mysqli_real_escape_string is the issue. I just finished re-writing the SQL statement and used prepare opposed to mysqli_real_escape_string and it works on both systems. with the old password. I dropped the database in the runtime and reimported it and tested and like magic it worked.

Comment: @frieder - to further on this issue. I found that using PDO vs MySQLi is more universal for databases. So, if we have to move over to something like Postgres it will be already supported unlike MySQLi which is exclusive to MySQL. however, I did read the performace in MySQLi vs PDO is much more efficent.

Comment: @frieder - Thank you for that info. I got my results back and my teacher gave me an extra 5pts

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP documentation:

*The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it.*

You should be able to verify the password using the function [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

```
$password_correct = password_verify($password, $hash)
```

Comment: I am doing the above method but the password is not being accepted. I use the default password Password123 on the dev system and when I do the dump and imported in the runtime system for our instructor it is not accepting the old password. but if I reset it to the Password123 on the runtime it works

Comment: @CalRob2005 So, just to make sure, have you verified that the hash is the same in both environments? It' supposed to be, since you simply imported the MySQL dump right? But if it's not the case, then you will have to figure out why. Maybe the production environment has something dumb enabled like `magic_quotes` on `php.ini` and this is messing things up.